# are Friday gains greater than Monday?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am looking for an if statement in R that will help me determine if Monday close is higher the Friday close, the point is to add it as an extra column.

I have tried the following which gives a plausible result:

> GSPC$GSPC.DIFF <- for(i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr)) {if(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4){GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF,5)}else{GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF, "")}}
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjEvp.png)

But changing statment 1 to append(GSPC.DIFF,GSPC$GSPC.Close)

> GSPC$GSPC.DIFF <- for(i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr)) {if(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4){GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF,GSPC$GSPC.Close)}else{GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF, "")}}

Gives the following:
[enter image description here][2]

do anyone know why it is not giving value to every five lines like in the first case?

here is where the value is collected from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjEvp.png)

Comment: can you say what you've tried so far? can you offer us a [mcve] (use `dput()` rather than a screenshot)?  Do you want to know for each week, or on average ... ???

Comment: Thank you for replying ! I have updated the question!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potentially useful approach (not the most elegant way I guess):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)
data <- tibble(
  Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020/04/01"), to = as.Date("2020/05/12"), by = "day"),
  Open = runif(42, min = 11500, max = 12600),
  Close = runif(42, min = 11500, max = 12600)
)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(day = weekdays(Date),
         week = week(Date)) %>%
  filter(day == "Monday" | day == "Friday") %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(Delta = ifelse(Close - lead(Open, 1) > 0, "Higher", "Lower")) %>%
  select(Date, week, Delta) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Delta))
```

With this output:

```
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   week [6]
  Date        week Delta 
  <date>     <dbl> <chr> 
1 2020-04-03    14 Higher
2 2020-04-10    15 Lower 
3 2020-04-17    16 Lower 
4 2020-04-24    17 Lower 
5 2020-05-01    18 Lower 
6 2020-05-08    19 Lower
```

From this input:

```
> data
# A tibble: 42 x 3
   Date         Open  Close
   <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2020-04-01 11816. 11955.
 2 2020-04-02 12367. 11906.
 3 2020-04-03 11950. 11668.
 4 2020-04-04 12471. 11653.
 5 2020-04-05 12535. 11756.
 6 2020-04-06 11550. 12013.
 7 2020-04-07 12081. 11793.
 8 2020-04-08 12482. 12444.
 9 2020-04-09 12107. 11550.
10 2020-04-10 12002. 11986.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the xts series to dataframe using `fortify.zoo()`, create a weekday column and calculate the percent difference between each day with the previous day.

```
DJI %>%
  fortify.zoo() %>%
  mutate(day = weekdays(Index), 
         diff_per = (DJI.Close - lag(DJI.Close))/lag(DJI.Close) * 100)


#        Index DJI.Open DJI.High DJI.Low DJI.Close DJI.Volume DJI.Adjusted       day     diff_per
#1   2007-01-03  12474.5  12474.5 12474.5   12474.5          0      12474.5 Wednesday           NA
#2   2007-01-04  12480.7  12480.7 12480.7   12480.7          0      12480.7  Thursday  0.049702954
#3   2007-01-05  12398.0  12398.0 12398.0   12398.0          0      12398.0    Friday -0.662624642
#4   2007-01-08  12423.5  12423.5 12423.5   12423.5          0      12423.5    Monday  0.205678335
#5   2007-01-09  12416.6  12416.6 12416.6   12416.6          0      12416.6   Tuesday -0.055543051
#6   2007-01-10  12442.2  12442.2 12442.2   12442.2          0      12442.2 Wednesday  0.206180330
#....
```

If you are interested only in Monday and Friday values, you can add `filter` in the above command.

```
 %>% filter(day %in% c('Monday', 'Friday'))
```

**data**

```
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

getSymbols('DJI')
```